# Referencing without captions appearing but keeping numbering

Tags: captions

From what I understand, in order to refer to a figure in the text and be able to access it via clicking, I use `\label{}`, and then in the text I use `\ref{}`, with the same name inside.

What I would like is for the figure to *not* have the caption appear, but to keep the numbering. So that in the text, there is still "1" that I can click to jump to the figure, but for there not to be "Figure 1" or "Figure 1: etc". If I try including `\caption*{}` (as I've seen on other answers), the numbering goes away and is replaced with "??" which is not what I want (although it still goes the picture when I click it).

I think getting rid of the `caption` package and associated uses of `\caption{}` would do the trick normally, but within the same document later on, I am planning on cross-referencing to figures in a document that uses the captions and the `caption` package quite heavily, so I figure I need to be able to have the `caption` package here.

Example code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Let's test this \ref{Fig:test}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{}
    \label{Fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard LaTeX `\label`-`\ref` cross-referencing mechanism relies on LaTeX making a successful association between (a) the argument of `\label` and (b) the most-recently-incremented counter variable. In the case of `figure` environments, the relevant counter variable is called `figure` as well. The `figure` counter gets incremented when `\caption{...}` is run inside a `figure` environment. However, because you've expressed a preference for *not* running `\caption` instructions, this standard cross-referencing mechanism isn't available to you.

Happily, though, a second mechanism is available, courtesy of the `hyperref` package which is loaded in your example. It provides the commands `\hypertarget{}{}` and `\hyperlink{}{}`, which you could use as follows:

- Write `\hypertarget{name}{some text}` to create a *target* somewhere inside the `figure` environment. (This is the sort-of equivalent of `\label`.)
- Write `\hyperlink{name}{some other text}` to create a hyperlink elsewhere in the document. (That's the sort-of equivalent of `\ref`.)
- Note that `name` has to be the same across the two commands. (Moreover, `name` has to be unique to the item to be cross-referenced, for obvious reasons.) In contrast, the second fields -- "some text" and "some other text" in the code snippets shown above -- need *not* be the same. In fact, one or both of these text fields can be left empty, as is done in the example below.

Compile the following code to see these recommendations in action. The red "figure" label is a clickable target; click on it from within a pdf browser and you'll be taken to the `figure` on the following page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
A cross-reference to the \hyperlink{fig:test}{figure} on the next page.   
\clearpage 

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \hypertarget{fig:test}{} % Note: 2nd arg is deliberately left blank
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

`\captionlistentry` (offered by the `caption` package) does increment the `figure` counter as well, so you get a valid reference, too, by simply replacing `\caption` with `\captionlistentry`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Let's test this \ref{Fig:test}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionlistentry{}
    \label{Fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Pros: This works with and without `hyperref`, and you could still have a "List of Figures" if wanted.